# Add new host to a running txloadbalancer

Tags: python, api, asynchronous, twisted, load-balancing

I am using txloadbalancer twisted API in my application and it works great. I have one problem tho, I can't figure out a way too add hosts to a running instance.

I use this function for now:

```
#pm is a ProxyManager
def addServiceToPM(pm, service):
    if isinstance(service, model.HostMapper):
        [service] = model.convertMapperToModel([service])
    for groupName, group in pm.getGroups(service.name):
        proxiedHost = service.getGroup(groupName).getHosts()[0][1]
        pm.getGroup(service.name, groupName).addHost(proxiedHost)
        tracker = HostTracking(group)
        scheduler = schedulers.schedulerFactory(group.lbType, tracker)
        pm.addTracker(service.name, groupName, tracker)
```

and run it with a new host

```
addServiceToPM(pm, HostMapper(proxy='127.0.0.1:8080', lbType=roundr,
               host='host2', address='127.0.0.1:10002'))
```

This adds the host correctly to the tracker, but not to the proxy service and it is thus not used in the load balancing. Do anyone have a clue about how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up staring at the source code until the answer appeared.

If you, as in my case, want to add a new host to a existing proxy and group you use

```
def addHostToLB(pm, proxy, group, newHost, newHostName):
    tracker = pm.getTracker(proxy, group)
    tracker.newHost(newHost, newHostName)
```